# Convert specific field to upper case by other field using sed

Tags: linux, bash, sed

Using sed I need to covert to upper case the second field when the field city=miami and city=chicago

My code now looks like this, it convert all the name to upper without filtering by city.

```
id,name,country,sex,year,price,team,city,x,y,z
266,Aaron Russell,USA,m,1989,50,12,miami,0,0,1
179872,Abbos Rakhmonov,UZB,m,1979,0,25,chicago,0,0,0
3662,Abby Erceg,NZL,m,1977,67,20,toronto,0,0,0
5554573,Amar Music,CRO,m,1991,110,24,miami,0,0,0
3931111,Anirban Lahiri,IND,m,1987,105,27,boston,0,0,0
98402,Anissa Khelfaoui,ALG,f,1967,45,2,toronto,0,0,0

sed 's/^\(\([^,]*,\)\{1\}\)\([^,]*\)/\1\U\3/'
```

My output:

```
id,name,country,sex,year,price,team,city,x,y,z
266,AARON RUSELL,USA,m,1989,50,12,miami,0,0,1
179872,ABBOS RAKHMONV,UZB,m,1979,0,25,chicago,0,0,0
3662,ABBY ERCEG,NZL,m,1977,67,20,toronto,0,0,0,
5554573,AMAR MUSIC,CRO,m,1991,110,24,miami,0,0,0,
393115111,ANIRBAN LAHIRI,IND,m,1987,105,27,boston,0,0,0
998460252,ANISSA KHELFAOUI,ALG,f,1967,45,2,toronto,0,0,0
```

Expected output. Only using sed.

```
id,name,country,sex,year,price,team,city,x,y,z
266,AARON RUSELL,USA,m,1989,50,12,miami,0,0,1
179872,ABBOS RAKHMONV,UZB,m,1979,0,25,chicago,0,0,0
3662,Abby Erceg,NZL,m,1977,67,20,toronto,0,0,0
5554573,AMAR MUSIC,CRO,m,1991,110,24,miami,0,0,0
393115111,Anirban Lahiri,IND,m,1987,105,27,boston,0,0,0
998460252,Anissa Khelfaoui,ALG,f,1967,45,2,toronto,0,0,0
```

Comment: You'll probably want to use the `/test/` command of `sed`. Another alternative is to include what you're looking for in the search pattern of the `s` command

Comment: Where are the additional digits coming from in your output and expected output for Anissa? Your code fails to filter therefore matching all lines. Adding a filter;  `sed '/miami\|chicago/s/^\(\([^,]*,\)\{1\}\)\([^,]*\)/\1\U\3/' file`

Answer (score 2):

Easier IMHO with `awk`:

```
awk  'BEGIN{city=8; FS=OFS=","}
$city=="miami" || $city=="chicago" {$2=toupper($2)} 1' file
```

Prints:

```
id,name,country,sex,year,price,team,city,x,y,z
266,AARON RUSSELL,USA,m,1989,50,12,miami,0,0,1
179872,ABBOS RAKHMONOV,UZB,m,1979,0,25,chicago,0,0,0
3662,Abby Erceg,NZL,m,1977,67,20,toronto,0,0,0
5554573,AMAR MUSIC,CRO,m,1991,110,24,miami,0,0,0
3931111,Anirban Lahiri,IND,m,1987,105,27,boston,0,0,0
98402,Anissa Khelfaoui,ALG,f,1967,45,2,toronto,0,0,0
```

Comment: You could also key off the heading row. `NR==1 {for (i=1;i<=NF;++i) { if ($i=="city") city=i } }`

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -E '/^([^,]*,){7}(miami|chicago),/{s/(^[^,]*,)([^,]+)/\1\U\2/}'
```

- This relies on matching comma number 1 and number 7 in each line (ie. to match field 2 and field 8). If a single field in the CSV contained (extra) quoted or escaped commas, this would break.
- Note that `\U` syntax is specific to GNU sed, and not portable.
- This task would probably be more clearly expressed in awk, and gawk can also handle quoted commas, using `FPAT`.